# URL doesn't change after using subDays() in blade - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have the following array to subtract 1 day in blade:

```
@php
$prv_day = $day->subDays(1);
@endphp
```

$prv_day output, which is fine :

```
Carbon {#392 ▼
  +"date": "2019-10-30 19:03:00.000000"
  +"timezone_type": 3
  +"timezone": "UTC"
}
```

The problem occurrs when I try to send the `$prv_day` in a route as follows :

```
<a href="{{route('upd.date', ['date' =>$prv_day])}}" class="btn btn-primary">Previous day</a>
```

The URL holds today's date and doesn't change to yesterday:

```
http://localhost/sharp/updtdate/2019-10-31%2019:51:18
```

Route :

```
Route::get('/updtdate/{date}', [
    'uses' => 'AnswerController@updt_date',
    'as' => 'upd.date',
    'middleware' => 'auth'
]);
```

Comment: what else are you doing with `$day` after the `subDays` call? `$day` and `$prv_day` are the same object

Comment: Next day, date with or without time ... Etc

Comment: you are subtracting a day then later adding a day? that would explain why you are getting todays date

Comment: Addition and subtraction are separated , each assigned to different variable.

Comment: The below solution solved the issue.

Comment: you do not get a new Carbon instance when you run those methods (they are adjusting the instance you are calling them on and returning that same instance) ... `$day` and `$prv_day` are references to the same carbon object ... they are not cloned

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to make that Carbon object to datetime string and append it with the URL. Use the following code.

```
$prv_day = $day->subDays(1)->toDateTimeString();
```

Answer (score 0):

code:

```
$date=\Carbon\Carbon::now()->subDays(1)->format('Y-m-d');
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. How does `subDays(30)` return the previous day?